# Wpf ComboBox with Checkbox Performance Problems

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I've got a WPF Combobox with about 1000 rows.
Each Row has a  checkbox to allow selecting mulltiple rows.

If nothing has been selected it opens just fine. Howeve if I've already selected something and now want to change my selection it takes about 30s for the ComboBox to open and it has for some reason scrolled to the bottom.

I'm using `VirtualizingStackPanel` but it doesn't seem to  fix the problem.

```
   <ComboBox
            x:Name="cbStockCat"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="2,0,2,0" 
            Padding="2,10,0,4" 
            materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Stock Category"
            materialDesign:HintAssist.IsFloating="True"
            StaysOpenOnEdit="True" 
            customProperties:EnterKeyTraversalExtension.IsEnabled="True"
            AllowDrop="True"
            IsEditable="True"
            ToolTip="{Binding StockCategoryCollection.ToolTipText}"
            TabIndex="{Binding StockCatTabIndex, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
            Text="{Binding StockCategoryCollection.Text, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding StockCategoryCollection}"                                                     
            Cursor="Hand">
        <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <CheckBox 
                    IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    Content="{Binding}"   
                    Background="{StaticResource BrushPrimaryLighter}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}" >
                </CheckBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello, can you plz add more information about your configuration (.NET Version, VS version, Add a part of your model and/or ViewModel)

Comment: I used your code exactly as is, but without `customProperties:EnterKeyTraversalExtension.IsEnabled="True"`, and I can add 10000 elements without any problems. Try removing that AP, if the problem persists then it's likely due to some parent element of this code disabling virtualization for all its children.

Comment: @MarkFeldman I've tried removing that line and it didn't do anything. Could be something to do with my ViewModel for the MultiSelect. I'll look into that part and post some of that code if I can't figure it out. Thanks for the suggestion.